# Divs are staying in one line?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this script and the problem with it is that I cannot find a way to make the divs that are created to float randomly on the page. They stay in the left corner. Do I need to change the body dimensions or change the position. I guess something is blocking them not to.
One more thing. If someone of you would revise the code and write re-write it following the *best practices* in JavaScript It will be appreciated!

```
(function create() {
    var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var count = 5;
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var numerousDivs = document.createElement("div");
        docFragment.appendChild(numerousDivs);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(docFragment);

    var fiveDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (i = 0; i < fiveDivs.length; i++) {
        div = fiveDivs[i];
        alter(div);
        moveDivs(div);
    }
}());

function moveDivs(div) {
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    var topPos = parseInt(Math.random() * (maxHeight - 40));
    div.style.top = topPos + "px";
    var left = parseInt(Math.random() * (maxWidth - 100));
    div.style.left + "px";
}
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code down to a simple testcase

Comment: so I suppose moveDivs contains the code to move the div, does that set the style of the divs to absolute? cause if not they will not move

Comment: Well they do move but only vertically and not horizontally. The stay in the predefined height of the body. This is an onload function.

Comment: can you post the code for the moveDivs function

Comment: There it is. Thank you Antony for the edit.

Comment: `div.style.left + "px";` seems like an obvious problem

Comment: look at last line of moveDivs, you are not assigning left, is that a typo? div.style.left + "px"; should be div.style.left = left + "px";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div.style.left + "px";` should be `div.style.left = left+"px";`.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.style.left + "px";
```

This is a typo.

```
div.style.left = left+"px";
```